# How to connect cordova application to PostgreSql and fetch data from the server via javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, postgresql, cordova

i want to fetch customers details from postgresSql server but i dont know how to do it. can anyone help me on that , i am working on cross platform android application by phoengap.

i want to fetch data via jquery or javascript

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need a middleman (Server side) function between you and the PostgreSQL, otherwise it's very risky.

Comment: i haven't tried anything so far, as i don't know what to do..can you please walk me through

Comment: It's not going to be solved in a single answer, you need to understand and plan exactly what you want to do, "server side" is a rather thick layer, could range from NodeJS through PHP, Django and custom built services, you need to be more specific and learn your way into it.

Comment: i want to do it with cordova-jdbc but got stucj in the jar file name.

Comment: i dont know form where to get class name of the driver